# TCP let server close connection first on let client close connection first

Tags: c, tcp

Suppose this is a simple stateless server.

1. If server close connection after handling the request and writing back the response, there must be too many connections in `CLOSE_WAIT` status.
2. If let client close connection first, there might be too many active connections in server side if the client doesn't close them.

Then how to handle this situation? Should I use 1 or 2 or other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If server close connection after handling the request and writing back the response, there must be too many connections in CLOSE_WAIT status.

No, but there will be a lot of TIME_WAIT states.

> If let client close connection first, there might be too many active connections in server side if the client doesn't close them.

So the server should use a read timeout.

In general it's best for the server to be the one that receives the first close. That way the TIME_WAIT states pile up at the clients, not the server, and the clients won't have a lot of connections so it isn't any kind of a problem.